# how to make a business layer working with different Models?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, interface, n-tier-architecture

I am designing the architecture of a .Net project in C#.
I will use EF.
I want to set a MVC pattern architecture.
Although I will start with a first Model implementation, I might have to use other Models that will be QUITE similar to the original one.

I obviously want to implement a single Business layer that would ideally work with both Model implementations.

So I suppose I will have to intensively rely on interfaces at some point.

USUALLY, I build my entities and context this way:

```
    public class Foo
    {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
... other properties
    }

    public class Bar
    {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual  Foo Fooo { get; set; }
... other properties
    }
    ...
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
    ...
    }
```

Now, in my case, I will have let's say 2 different models.
On top of the precedently written Foo and Bar classes, I will have:

```
 public class Foo2
    {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
... other properties
    }

    public class Bar2
    {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo Fooo { get; set; }
... other properties
    }
    ...
    public class MyContext2 : DbContext
    {
    ...
    }
```

Now how to set a single business layer that can deal either with MyContext or MyContext2 ?

I suppose the the fist step is to create interfaces for For Foo / Foo2 and Bar / Bar2:

```
public interface IFoo
    {
     int Id { get; set; }
     string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IBar
    {
     int Id { get; set; }
     string Name { get; set; }
     IFoo Fooo { get; set; }
    }
```

Then what????